# SVN Branching - Visual Studio Development Environment working with images and PDFs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, cdn

We are maintaining the code a large ecommerce site with thousands of images and large PDF files.

We are very good about creating SNV branches as we work through bug reports naming the branches with the Bug Tracking Number.

We are hitting some major problems because the branches are taking 20 min to create and upload due to the large amount of images and PDF files.

Since we are only working on CODE and Design related images however, we have NO NEED for product images or PDF brochures, within our solution.

**What is the best approaching in setting a development environment using Visual Studio using solutions > projects (DAL, BLL , WEB, etc..) but not having all the extra ‘media’ files?**

We would still like to have \images\ with the design elements so we can see the site design.

What about having the extra ‘media’ files located on a mini CND within the same server with a Web.Config setting pointing to it ?

Any thoughts/ solutions for this?

**UPDATE - WORKING**

*Please see my answer below for details.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just not include those types of assets in the code repo. There's really no need to have PSDs and such as part of your Visual Studio solution. If you continue to do that each branch will take a long time to create.

Instead, I'd create a separate repository altogether for image asset files. That repo can sit next to your code repo but would be handled separately at the server. This way you don't make new version of them each time you branch your code. As well, designers can work inside that repo without having to worry about the code repo.

Good luck!

Comment: Can I create a Visual Studio project that contains only assets? Will it still build and run the website bringing in the assets as needed?

Comment: I suppose you could, yes, but that sort of defeats the purpose because you'd want the assets in a separate repository, right? My advice would be to not include the assets as part of the Visual Studio solution. They should reside in their own repository.

Comment: see my post below - and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what we ended up doing to solve the problem.

1. In the /image/ directory we removed all the ‘non-design’ assets such as product images, retailer images, etc … including PDF files.
2. Created a completely separate domain name/ftp for all the moved assets in #1, such as CDN.DOMAINNAME.COM
3. Refactored code/design pages to point to the CDN location for all assets 
   example:  /images/products/<%#Eval("productImg")%>  />
4. Deleted the entire SVN project (we use [BeanStalkApp](http://beanstalkapp.com/) ) , deleted the project from local drives.
5. Created (2) SVN and local folders:
   DOMAINNAME.COM     and    CDN.DOMAINNAME.COM

Our project folder  DOMAINNAME.COM size  went from 24 MB to 3.30 MB.

The size of the CDN.DOMAINNAME.COM has the other 20 MB of assets.

**Designers and programmers** commit to DOMAINNAME.COM every few hours including creating branches which takes a few minutes, before, it would take 20-30 min.

**Designers** commit to CDN.DOMAINNAME.COM only once or twice a day. Our programmers chose to stay away from CDN.DOMAINNAME.COM SVN for the most part.

We recently used [Beanstalk’s Deployment Tool (Automatically)](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/68162-what-are-deployments) -- When a new product image is posted to the SVN, BeanStalk pushed the new files up to the server automatically – so cool!

Everything is working great with the new structure and both designers and programmers are very happy.